# Configure manifest.mf classpath in ear

Tags: maven, classpath, ear, wildfly-10, manifest.mf

I have an ear application which has 3 modules:

web.war

services.jar(ejb)

domain.jar(ejb)

I worked with maven tutorial:[tutorial](http://javapapo.blogspot.gr/2014/05/java-ee7-and-maven-project-for-newbies_30.html)

At the end author says about problems with manifest.mf in web module and suggesting some solutions. But this not worked for me. I think configuration is broken not only in that case. In my ear MANIFEST (classpath) i have also prefix "lib/" before services module(services are separated jar as ejb module in my app).

I saw i can use my specific prepared Manifest.mf, but i don't know how to configure it manually. Could I duplicate jars in my app modules? For example add domain.jar in services and web? Is it correct?

I have specific structure:

1.sample-ear with web and services module

2.sample-web with sample servlet(without dependencies from other project in code).

3.sample-services with dao classes(using entities)

4.sample-domain with entity beans

I tried modify manifests in every package, but I didn't find a solution. When i want to run my application on WildFly10 i get NoDefClassError (Class from domain.jar used in service.jar). Could anyone help to configure it?

On the other hand maybe you have better maven configuration in project and manually configuring the manifest.mf is not needed.

Comment: Please show your application.xml. You should not need to use manifest Class-Path entries in a correctly constructed EAR on WildFly.

Comment: I tested my project today and i get some detials. But first, my application.xml has 2 modules: web and services( is it okay?). In this tutorial in ear pom.xml we dclared to have 2 modules, and domain will be the dependency of services layer.

Comment: I've moved my dao class to services, and WF started succesfully. But when i make get request to my servlet invoking->services bean->dao, I get NoClassDefFoundError on my entity bean. So there must be something wrong with dependency with domain module.